# Create folders in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to **create folders using flask** . I Google for this a lot but didn't find any help. Evey search shows me the **folder structure of flask** but I want to know how can I create folders using code.

Actually I want to **create folders for every user at register** time.So suggest me a way how can I create a simple empty folder at particular path in flask.

Comment: Create a folder where? On the server? You'd do that the same way you'd do it in any other Python code, using [`os.mkdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir). However, this usually is *not* how you should store application data, use a database instead.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`os.mkdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir) or [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) according to your need.

```
import os

os.makedirs('/path/to/directory')
```

Answer (score 3):

create folders for every user at register time.
You can override the default  constructor of sqlalchemy orm like this and do custom stuff
inside the function. Here is semi working code.

```
from app import db
import os

class User(db.Model):
    # ...
    
    folder = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # do custom stuff call folder create method here
        
        self.create_folder()
        
    
    
    # method to create folder
    def create_folder(self):
          
          #give path to location where you want to create folder
          path = "my path where i want to create folder"
          os.mkdir(path)
          
         
          #update some property in User database
          
          self.folder = "path to my user folder"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/users/'

@app.route('/register', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def register():
    username = request.form.get("username")
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = username.strip().capitalize()
        user_folder = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], username)
        os.mkdir(user_folder)
        return f"folder is created under the name {username} and the full path is {user_folder}"
    return """
    <form method="post" action="/register">
    <input type="text" name="username" required>
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>
    """
```